# How to copy files from installer without install

Tags: batch-file, windows-installer, nsis

I have created installer using NSIS.

I have one batch file which needs to run if automatic  installation is failed (Installer checks whether any version of the software is already present if present the first uninstall it.) .

How can I run the batch file from installer without installing it ?

Comment: Sorry but your question is off topic, you have not provided a minimal, complete and verifiable example.

Comment: Regardless of that your question is about the use of a particular piece of software, not about programming. Your advice is to therefore read the usage information for the software, and then attempt to implement what you've learned before posting a question.

Comment: "needs to run if automatic installation is failed" do you actually mean automatic uninstallation here?

Answer (score 0):

NSIS does not really care if you extract files to `$InstDir` or somewhere else:

```
!define UninstId "MyAppBlahBlah"
!include LogicLib.nsh

Function RunMyBatch
  InitPluginsDir
  SetOutPath $PluginsDir
  File "myfiles\mybatch.bat"
  StrCpy $0 "$SysDir\cmd.exe"
  IfFileExists $0 +2
    ExpandEnvStrings $0 "%COMSPEC%"
  nsExec::Exec '"$0" /C "$PluginsDir\mybatch.bat"'
  Pop $0 ; Exit code
  SetOutPath $Temp ; Don't hold lock on $PluginsDir
FunctionEnd

Function .onInit
  ReadRegStr $0 HKLM "Software\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${UninstId}" "UninstallString"
  ${If} $0 != ""
    !insertmacro UninstallExisting $0 $0 ; https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Auto-uninstall_old_before_installing_new
    ${If} $0 <> 0
      Call RunMyBatch ; Run batch if uninstall old failed
    ${EndIf}
  ${EndIf}
FunctionEnd

Function .onInstFailed
  Call RunMyBatch ; Run batch if install failed
FunctionEnd
```